# How to make whole grid stay the same size with flexbox when adding more grid cells with js DOM?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I am currently doing the odin project Etch-A-sketch challenge.
I currently have it so that using JavaScript I create 16 row divs, with 16 grid squares inside each row div. So it is a 16 x 16 grid.

How do I make it so that when I put more grid squares into the container the whole grid stays the same size and the gird squares get smaller or larger in the container without it spilling over the container walls with flexbox?

Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/Alex-Swan/pen/jOyMwzm

Javascript:

```
/* This function creates 16x16 grid or what ever input the user has given, the event listner at the
 bottom of the function makes it that when a user hovers over a grid square it turns black. 
*/
function fullGrid(e) {
  for (let i = 0; i < e; i++) {
    row = document.createElement("DIV");
    container.appendChild(row);
    row.className = "row";
    for (let i = 0; i < e; i++) {
      square = document.createElement("DIV");
      row.appendChild(square);
      square.className = "gridSquare";
    }
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < gridSquare.length; i++) {
    gridSquare[i].addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
      gridSquare[i].className += " squareBlack";
    });
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  border: black solid 1px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  height: 6%;
}
.gridSquare {
  border: #444242 solid 1px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.3%;
}

.squareBlack {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

In JavaScript I calculated to height by dividing the GridSquare amount by the 400px size of the container. Also i changed the CSS box-sizing to border box.

Javascript:

```
function fullGrid(e) {
  for (let i = 0; i < e; i++) {
    row = document.createElement("DIV");
    container.appendChild(row);
    row.className = "row";
    for (let i = 0; i < e; i++) {
      square = document.createElement("DIV");
      row.appendChild(square);
      square.className = "gridSquare";
      square.style.width = "100%";               // <----- HERE
      let height = 400 / parseInt(squareAmount);  // <----- HERE
      square.style.height = `${height}px`;       // <----- HERE
    }
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < gridSquare.length; i++) {
    gridSquare[i].addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
      gridSquare[i].className += " squareBlack";
    });
  }
}
```